# Accessing value from WinRT component that is continously updated from managed code

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, com, windows-runtime

I am writing an application that will do some processing on the live preview images on windows phone 8. To achieve a good performance, I decided to use to the native interfaces provided with new sdk. Everythings work Ok for initializing the camera in native side, and feeding frames to a Image component in xaml. Now, I will write the code that will run in OnFrameAvailable method.

My problem is getting a processed value from the native component. Just to make things as simple as possible I just set an integer value in OnFrameAvailable and wrote an accessor of this value through a WinRT component to make it accesible in managed side.

I got stuck on what is an elegant way of accessing this value. When I try to access it in a loop in a thread i get the notorious "attempted to read or write protected memory " exception. I know the code does not make very much sense but I tried to minimize to point out the issue.
Here is how I do it:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        nativeCapture = new NativeCapture();
        while (nativeCapture.Done == false) ;
        viewFinderBrush.SetSource(nativeCapture.NPhotoCaptureDevice);
        DrawElementThread = new Thread(drawElementsFunction);
        DrawElementThread.Start();
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
    void drawElementsFunction()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            int a = nativeCapture.DetectedRectangleCoordinates; // Exception occurs here
        }

    }
```

Here you'll also notice that I am accsessing another value, Done, but I dont get the exception for it. However, I should note that is just set in the constructor of the native component whereas DetectedRectangleCoordinates is set everytime OnFrameAvailable called which I expect anytime a preview frame from the camera is available.

Therefore, I susptected that there might be some locking mechanism on WinRT components. Each time the OnFrameAvaible method called DetectedRectangleCoordinates becomes unaccessible. However, I could not find a statement about this and couldn't figure out how to debug such a thing.

I would really appreciate if you provide me with some pointers related to this or similar issues? Is it something related to access mechanisms in WinRT components? Or it is a bad threading practice I am doing? If so, how would I synchronize the thread in managed code and native code?

EDIT:
Putting a breakpoint on the line giving the exception and stepping does not cause the exception, and I get the expected value.

EDIT: 
I put a breakpoint on the get function on native side. this pointer is pointing to null there. I could not understand why it is because it is being called from the object that is just constructed. ( nativeCapture object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked quite some time on what may be going wrong, but adding the code to Loaded event handler of the page solved the issue. I am not sure what it is related about, but when the code piece I have given in the question is run in OnNavigatedTo method, nativeCapture component might have self null pointer (this->) on its methods. 
I hope this could help people if they have similar problems.